# New Table on Database

Tags: sql, database

Is there an easy way to create a table in the DB which contains both sku and qty fields?  Can I do this via SQL?

Comment: Naturally you can use SQL to create a database table. However, what is your objective here? Please give a bit more information.

Comment: The objective is to create a table which will have stock levels updated via a webservices system from a supplier.  There are several thousand products to be updated every 15 minutes.  The webservice uses SKU as the unique identifier.  I am not great with databases and SQL, my remit is HTML and CSS.  When I have attempted to copy the sku and qty columns from elsewhere, I cannot get the two columns to line up if that makes any sense.  The sku values ends for example on line 3000 and the qty values begin on line 3001.  I would really appreciate as much help as anyone can give here, thank you.

Comment: There are already elements in the database that hold these values. I'd caution you against creating a new table in magento. It would be time well spent if you take a look at the existing tables instead.

Comment: But I need one table to hold both values and as far as I can see, there isn't one.

Comment: Don't do this. Really. Look for someone who knows what he is doing, your customer will thank you id he isn't an idiot. It is hard to work with and integrations (whatever you integrate) is hard work. Don't do it alone, you can do a lot things wrong.

Comment: Agree with @FabianBlechschmidt If your forte is not being a developer, you would be out of your depth here. It would be great to learn this, but already your implementation is way wrong. I added an answer showing code that updates product stock, via a cron/pull from external system

Answer (score 1):

The code below is a snippet from a dataflow based importer, that updates stock, pulled in via webservice. The actual pull code from the webservice is not included, as it is a whole module.

The code uses the stock models directly thus making the process faster (using the base product models will be slow)

It has been coded to only do saves if data was changed, which also helps with speed.

This uses magento dataflow, thus you can use standard magento import/export csv format, where the csv format is:

sku,qty

```
class ProxiBlue_Importer_Model_Convert_Adapter_Apparel_Stock extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Convert_Adapter_Product {
    /*
     * saveRow 
     *
     * params args array
     * return array
     */

    public function saveRow(array $importData) {
        // sanity checks
        $required = array('sku', 'qty');
        foreach ($required as $field) {
            if (!key_exists($field, $importData) || strlen(trim($importData[$field])) == 0) {
                $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Skipping import row, required column "%s" not present/blank.', $field);
                Mage::throwException($message);
            }
        }

        // load the parent product
        $product = $this->getProductModel()
                ->reset();
        $store = Mage::app()->getDefaultStoreView();

        $product->setStoreId($store->getId());
        $productId = $product->getIdBySku($importData['sku']);

        if ($productId) {
            $canSave = false;
            $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
            $stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();

            if (!$stockItemId) {
                $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
                $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
            }
            $currentQty = $stockItem->getQty();
            if ($this->getVar('debug', false) == true) {
                mage::log('stock debug: ' . $importData['sku'] . ' : ' . $currentQty . ' <-> ' . $importData['qty']);
            }
            if ($currentQty != $importData['qty']) {
                $canSave = true;
                $stockItem->setQty($importData['qty']);
                mage::log('stock: ' . $importData['sku'] . ' : ' . $currentQty . ' -> ' . $importData['qty']);
            }
            try {
                if ($canSave) {
                    if ($stockItem->getQty() > 0) {
                        $stockItem->setIsInStock(True);
                    } else {
                        $stockItem->setIsInStock(False);
                    }
                    $stockItem->save();
                    //mage::log('Update Stock for ' . $importData['sku']);
                }
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Error importing related for sku "%s" - error was "%s".', $importData['parent_sku'], $e->getMessage());
                Mage::throwException($message);
            }
        } else {
            $message = Mage::helper('customer')->__('Skipping import row, product with sku "%s" not found.', $importData['parent_sku']);
            Mage::throwException($message);
        }

        return $canSave;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take this as references:

TABLE simplenews_news

```
CREATE TABLE `simplenews_news` (
`id`  int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`title`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
`category_id`  int(10) NOT NULL ,
`desc`  varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
`status`  varchar(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT disabled ,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

For more detail you can see at this [magento tutorial](http://www.mage-world.com/blog/lesson-2-the-model-and-the-database.html). I find it easy to follow.